# CAGradientLayer bounds not changing

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-graphics

I have a `CAGradientLayer` which is added to a `UIVIew`, when I rotate the device the view that it is added to increases in size (with autolayout) however the CA layer doesn't change its size.

I have tried implementing the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method and setting the layers frame in there but it doesn't make any difference.

Once the device is rotated if I navigate away from the view and then back to it then the layer gets drawn correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could override `- (void)layoutSubviews` in your UIView subclass and then update the layers frame.

Comment: That works a treat, I was assuming that the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` did the same thing but obviously not.